# Select last inserted records and grouping mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im having a table with notes. Below is a small sample of data of my db.

```
Id  register_no     name        classification      possibility
1   112             Ben         Red                 10%
2   112             Ben         Red                 10%
3   113             Ben         Red                 20%
4   112             Ben         Amber               30%
5   112             Ben         Amber               10%
6   113             Ben         Amber               30%
7   113             Ben         Red                 10%
8   112             Ben         Red                 50%
```

I’m sorry i interpreted the question in a wrong manner.

Actually what i wanted is to retrieve the last inserted record for each register_no because sales_log table holds a list progress...

for an example 
Register_no 112 has 12 records in the database and the last record is 90% (it progressed from 10,40,60% so all of these records are in the db)

what i want is to get the 90% of register_no 112 and so on... its not just one record... there is around 500 register_no and i want to get the last entry for each register_no

hope it makes sense this time

Comment: What about the 90%? I don't understand that part.

Comment: is it that you want to fetch only maximum records for each register id? e.g. ids 6 & 8 are selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this query to get the notes for register numbers having maximum `id` value:

```
SELECT n1.*
FROM   notes n1
       LEFT JOIN notes n2
           ON (n1.register_no = n2.register_no AND n1.id < n2.id)
WHERE  n2.id IS NULL;
```

Source: [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Comment: there are around 200 register numbersand various counts of records. i cant use the limit.

Comment: okay then you can remove LIMIT clause. can you elaborate your exact requirements?

Comment: sorry that i had put the question up wrong. i have explained it will hope it makes sense now..

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM (`sales_log`) WHERE 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 2
```

Telling msyql to match 'name = ben' will never find mandy's id 7

Comment: Why `WHERE 1`? That is a tautology.

Comment: @mschr there was a problem in the question... i have corrected it. If you could check it again and provide with a solution it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM sales_log WHERE `classification` =  'red' ORDER BY `Id` DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT data.* 
FROM sales_log AS data
JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MAX(Id) as Id 
        FROM sales_log 
        GROUP BY register_no
    ) AS newest
    ON data.Id = newest.Id
```

Result:

```
'8', '112', 'Ben', 'Red', '50'
'7', '113', 'Ben', 'Red', '10'
```

Edit: I just looked at @Omesh's link, apparently the solution he posted is a lot faster. It produces the exact same output as my query.